# Name of interface method "leak" implementation details

Tags: c#, object-oriented-design, naming, api-design

I have a class which implements an interface and have responsibility to create item and "maintain" collection of created items.

Class have method `GetOrCreate(int id)` which return instance of created item.

```
public class PoolOfItems : IPoolOfItems
{
    public Item GetOrCreate(int id) { }
}
```

Requirements for `GetOrCreate` method that in case when item, for given `id`, is already created, we need provide already created instance.

What is the most "understandable" name for method `GetOrCreate` can be used?

I afraid that name `GetOrCreate` describes implementation of the interface. And `Get` and `Create` names can be misleading when used with implementation.

Comment: Naming can be considered as "opinion-based" only when you don't care about used names in your code base. If you invest some effort in naming(hoping it pays you back when you read the code) - you will end up with different rules and best practices in same way as some `design pattern` question can be "opinion-based" because you can use "Factory" or "Builder" pattern

Comment: "What is the name of this thing" questions are allowed here, even though most of them don't produce a viable answer (because programmers think everything has a name).  However, "What *should* I name this thing" questions are specifically off-topic here.  See [Are “name that thing” questions on-topic,](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2380/1204) and [On the troubles of naming and terminology](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6586/1204)

Comment: If you are concerned about exposing details of the implementation, just call the method "GetInstance". However, the fact that the same instance may be reused, could have severe consequences for the user of the pool, if that instance contains any mutable data.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think "GetOrCreate" is already pretty clear.  I don't really understand what the last paragraph in your question means.

Comment: Last paragraph is about concern that another implementation of `IPoolOfItems` can create  new instance of `Item` on every call. In this case name `GetOrCreate` is misleading

Answer (score 1):

`GetOrCreate` communicates that the method can create an item. If that behavior is part of the method's contract then it should be communicated to users of the interface. If the method were just called `Get`, callers would be left wondering what happens when there is no item with the specified ID. Does it return null? Throw an exception? `GetOrCreate` avoids that ambiguity.

On the other hand, if creating an item isn't part of the method's contract but is a possible *implementation* of its contract, `GetOrCreate` is problematic because it implies a certain behavior that may not match the real implementation. In this case the more ambiguous `Get` would be more appropriate, but the method should be documented accordingly.

Comment: +1 Personally, I'd call it get and include a doc comment specifying the required behaviour of the method and circumstances that the behaviour is implementation specific (such as if no object exists).